# Scala subclass object to super class object assignment

Tags: scala, subclass

Examining Scala inheritance I run into the misunderstanding.
The code is:

```
sealed trait List[+A] // `List` data type, parameterized on a type, `A`
case object Nil extends List[Nothing] // A `List` data constructor representing the empty list
case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]

object List { // `List` companion object. Contains functions for creating and working with lists.
  def sum(ints: List[Int]): Int = ints match { // A function that uses pattern matching to add up a list of integers
    case Nil => 0 // The sum of the empty list is 0.
    case Cons(x,xs) => x + sum(xs) // The sum of a list starting with `x` is `x` plus the sum of the rest of the list.
  }

  def product(ds: List[Double]): Double = ds match {
    case Nil => 1.0
    case Cons(0.0, _) => 0.0
    case Cons(x,xs) => x * product(xs)
  }

  def apply[A](as: A*): List[A] = // Variadic function syntax
    if (as.isEmpty) Nil
    else Cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))
}

val l1 = List(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
println(product(l1))
```

As far as I understand relations between `List[+A]` and `Cons[+A]` are that `List[+A]` is super "class", `Cons[+A]` is subclass of `List[+A]`.

`l1` is instance of `Con[+A]`.
`l1` is passed to `product` method where input params `ds` has type `List` that knows nothing about its subclass `Cons`.

**So the question is how the assignment of subclass object to super class object could be explained?**

Comment: `s/to super class object/to a parameter of superclass type/`. Do you have any experience with OOP?

Comment: Side note: `case Cons(0.0, _) => 0.0` goes against IEEE-754. A counterexample is `0.0 * Double.NaN`, which evaluates to `Double.NaN`.

Comment: @Victor Moroz, I thought yes. But I'm here because the particular example is not clear for me.

Comment: What exactly is unclear? You have a variable/parameter of type `List[Double]`, you can assign/pass to it any object of type `List[Double]` or any subtype, e.g. `Cons[Double]` since `List` is covariant, as in any other OOP lanugage. Or the question was how `product` does matching and extracts `Cons`/`Nil` from something of type `List`?

Comment: @VictorMoroz, thanks for your reply. So I came from Ruby that is not strongly typed language. No, pattern matching is clear for me. How is it possible to assign variable of subtype (Cons[+A]) to variable of patent type (List[+A]), because Cons[+A] may have its own methods which are not presented in List[+A].

Comment: Additional methods in `Cons` simply become hidden when you assign it to a `List` type variable. All `animal`s `move` (presumably), but `cow` also gives milk. If you assign object of type `cow` to a variable of type `animal`, you can only call `.move`, but not `.give_milk`. It's still a `cow` inside though.

Comment: @Victor Moroz, could you please add your last comment as an answer, I will mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Additional methods in `Cons` simply become hidden when you assign it to a `List` type variable. All `Animal`s can move (presumably), but `Cow` which `extends Animal` also gives milk. If you assign an object of type `Cow` to a variable of type `Animal`, you can only call `.move`, but not `.give_milk`. It's still a `Cow` inside though.